# Can we Determine the Specific Equations for these Functions?

Tags: functions, polynomials, numerical-methods, approximation

Recently, I have been reading about the **Runge Phenomenon** .

The **Runge Phenomenon** describes a situation in which a polynomial is used to approximate another function using a fixed number of evenly spaced points - however, the polynomial being used to approximate this function can be shown to exhibit oscillatory behavior towards the end points of the range over which the function being approximated on (i.e. higher error):

[image]

The above picture demonstrates an example of the **Runge Phenomenon**  - the "red colored" function is approximated using a "$5$th order polynomial" ("blue") and a "$9$th order polynomial" ("green") : as we can see, the quality of the approximation for both the "$5$th order polynomial" and the "$9$th order polynomial" begin to decrease in quality (i.e. higher error) when examined at interpolation points towards the extremities

**My Question:**. As we know, a "$n$-th order polynomial" is a polynomial function where the highest exponential term can not be greater than "$n$" - **but in the picture above, could we determine the mathematical equations of the "blue" and "green" curves?**

For instance, suppose we were given :

- The equation of the "red" function: $y = \frac{1}{1+25x^2}$
- "$n$" (e.g. $n = 20$) evenly spaced points between $-1$ and $1$ (e.g. $-1, -0.8, -0.6, \dots 0.8, 1.0$) corresponding to "$x$"
- The value of the "red" function (i.e. $y$ values) at each of these "$n$" points

**Given the above information, how would we determine the equation of the "blue" and "green" functions? How exactly are we interpolating? Essentially, (to obtain the equations of the "blue" and "green" functions) are we fitting polynomial regression models to these points?**

Can someone please comment on this?

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon

Comment: "the "red colored" polynomial function" - I don't think it is a polynomial function.

Comment: @ Gary: thank you for your reply! I made that correction!

Comment: Have you tried Lagrange interpolation?

Comment: @ Gary: Thank you for your reply! I was just curious to know whether the Runge Phenomena would apply to "all" polynomial interpolations. For example - if we used the Lagrange Interpolation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial), could we also expect oscillatory behavior to occur towards the extremities? Thank you so much!

Comment: If you read the last line of the intro of the page you linked, it says "Lagrange interpolation is susceptible to Runge's phenomenon of large oscillation. As changing the points $x_{j}$ requires recalculating the entire interpolant, it is often easier to use Newton polynomials instead."

Comment: Notice that the power series of this function, to which the polynomial approximations should converge for an approximation centered at $x=0$, has a radius of convergence of $1/5$, thus diverges for $x$ outside the interval $[-1/5,1/5]$. It is thus natural that the polynomial approximations reflect that divergence.